# Understanding "anonymous transaction"

Tags: privacy

I have read

> In the original Satoshi whitepaper, it was recommended that Bitcoin
>   users use a new address for each transaction to avoid the transactions
>   being linked to a common owner.

But in reality, when A buys a bitcoin from B, A sends money to B to B's account in an exchange (or whatever account.) It seems that B can be identified via this dollar transaction by an exchange or the authority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone can stay anonymous if he wants to stay anonymous, bitcoin was designed to put banks aside peoples cant understand that, that can be understanded only from peoples wich understand the term "privacy", 2018 & peoples buy bitcoins from exchanges only if their have verify their identify verified, thoose peoples dont understand the term "privacy", if you want privacy hold & use p2p exchanges - localbitcoins instead of online exchanges services. 
A purely peer-to-peer version of electronic cash would **allow online payments to be sent directly from one party to another without going through a financial institution**.

Answer (score 0):

The original Satoshi client (now called Bitcoin Core) was developed from the whitepaper. Exchanges, online hosted wallets and many other things requiring identification came later. You can still run Bitcoin Core or a similar wallet on your desktop and many people value the anonymity.

You are right that when you use an exchange or another service where you are required to identify yourself, link bank accounts or, other similar activities you can be identified.

Comment: Yes you are right that these identifications came later. But how can one anonymously handle these dollar exchanges?

Comment: @171124 Your best bet is a service like localbitcoins.com or similar.

Comment: Just try to understand the mechanism.

Comment: @171124 Added to answer.